# Update $unset command eats up all ram on large collection

Tags: mongodb, unset

Using MongoDB, I'm trying to remove a column from a collection that contains ~3 million records.

```
db.Listing.update( {}, { $unset: { Longitude: 1 } }, false, true);
```

When I execute this command, the RAM on the server continues to go up until it runs out of RAM and then the server is hosed and needs to be physically rebooted. Is there a better way to remove a column from a large collection that won't hose the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect your problem is the system OOM killer. You should make sure you aren't limiting the resources for mongod. See this: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Checking+Server+Memory+Usage

http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2009/09/30/how-the-linux-oom-killer-works/

If you are using a virt. system like openvz you might want to stop , or adjust the over-committing feature.

Comment: It's funny that you say make sure you don't limit the resources to mongod, as it seems that mongod is using EVERYTHING that the system has. I'm not using linux, I'm actually using Windows Server 2008. Could that be the issue, that the Win Server 2008 implementation of mongod isn't very good yet? One other thing I noticed, mongod captures memory to use for caching collections but it never releases that memory, it stays in cache so I have to restart the mongod service frequently to reclaim the mem and keep the server operational.

Comment: All implementations use memory mapped files and it is the OS's job to allocate memory for that. Did you notice the section in that link I included about "cached" memory? Is that what you mean by all memory?